# Limits of functions and left hand right hand limit

Tags: limits

Use the $\epsilon$,$\delta$-definition of limits to show that
$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}f(x)=L$

I started by defining the left- and right-hand limit respectively. and then I assume that the limit is $L$ when $f(x)$ goes to $a$. but I have no idea how to continue. can anyone help? thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: Remember that there are two things you need to do. To prove the right hand implication, you need to show that "If $lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) =L$, then $lim_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x) =L$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x) =L$." Then, to prove the other direction, you need to show that "if $lim_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x) =L$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x) =L$, then $lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) =L$."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delta epsilon method of proving this (which I assume is what you want) by the following.

Right-handed limit (when $x>a$)

There exists $\delta$ such that if $x-a < \delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Left-handed limit (when $x<a$)

There exists $\delta$ such that if $a - x < \delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

The two-sided limit is defined as :
There exists $\delta$ such that if  $|x-a| < \delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

We can split up the absolute value around $x-a$ above on the two sided limit in the following way:

If $x-a>0$, or equivalently if $x>a$

$|x-a| < \delta$
Becomes
$x-a < \delta$
The same as the right sided limit definition.

If $x-a<0$, or equivalently if $x<a$

$|x-a| < \delta$
Becomes
$-(x-a)  < \delta$

$a - x < \delta$

The same as the left sided limit definition.

This means that,  in order for the two sided limit to exist,  both the right handed and left handed limits must exist.